# Loading HTML templates synchronously

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

I am trying to render a template a template in Typescript, which is not happening. Here's the code and the browser error:

```
class QuestionView extends Backbone.View{
    template: (data:any) => string;

    constructor(options?:any){
        var question = this;
        require(["text!add-new-question.html"],
            function(html) {
                question.template = _.template(html);
            }
        );
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    }

    render(){
        var data = this.model.toJSON();
        var html = this.template(data);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<QuestionView> has no method 'template' Main.ts:49
QuestionView.render Main.ts:49
(anonymous function) Main.ts:57
```

Update:

As pointed out below, this is happening because of the require functions returns after the the render is finished its execution. I've trying running with a `setInterval()` and it works. How can I make the require function a synchronous one?

Comment: I bet the `require` callback is returning after you're executing `var html = this.template(data);`. Since `template` hasn't been assigned to yet, it doesn't exist and throws that error.

Comment: You've got a point. How do I make this synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using jquery-ajax insted of require.js

```
var ajxParam: JQueryAjaxSettings = {
   async: false, timeout: 200000,
   url: "http://somthing", dataType: "html",
   cache: false,
   success: (htmltext: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) => {

   },
   error: (jqXHR: JQueryXHR, textStatus: string, errorThrow: string) => {
           // show error?
   }
}
$.ajax(ajxParam);
//you can bind your data here
```